# Site2Site tunnel via SSL VPN?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, cisco

i have tried convincing my opposite office of the tunnel in question to get site-2-site ipsec up and running.

However they are not really into that and run everything via SSL VPN..

### Is it possible to create a site to site tunnel via SSL VPN?

How i would setup the ipsec on our Cisco ASA 5505

```
local net 192.168.0.0/18
remote net 10.50.0.0/18
IKE proposal pre-share-3des-sha, pre-share-aes-256-sha
IPSec proposal ESP-AES-128-SHA, ESP-AES-128-MD5, ESP-AES-192-SHA, ESP-AES-192-MD5, ESP-AES-256-SHA, ESP-AES-256-MD5, ESP-3DES-SHA, ESP-3DES-MD5, ESP-DES-SHA, ESP-DES-MD5
```

Comment: This question is too vague, what did u try to do? which model of router do you have? how the network are set?

Comment: using the anyconnect via VPN SSL works fine.. But once connected, i have no internet (WAN) access besides the remote vpn point. Nor do I have access to our own domain (LAN). Its a cisco asa 5505, i actually have 3 local subnets but using a general one as shown in edit would suffice

Comment: I suggest to read this link http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/SSL-VPN

Comment: i know what the SSL VPN is brother :)

Comment: Are you asking how to do site-to-site VPNs with CISCO IOS, or are you asking if it can be done at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cisco asa doesn't support ssl site to site vpn. so if you use cisco asa it is not possible to create a site to site tunnel via ssl vpn because ssl vpn is used for remote access user vpns. you can configure ipsec lan to lan or if you don't have a fixed ip address on the other peer you can configure easy vpn.

have a look at the good cisco docs for asdm and cli:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/asdm64/configuration_guide/wizard_vpn.html#wp1053062

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa72/configuration/guide/site2sit.html

if you are not familiar with the cisco cli you better use the asdm vpn wizard. it's a fast and easy way do build vpns.

Comment: I don't normally downvote answers, but this is **patently** not so.  There is no technical reason whatsoever that an SSL VPN cannot be used for site-to-site connectivity.  I agree that it's not the best solution (IMHO, IPSec would be much better), and it may well be that CISCO IOS does not support it, but SSL VPNs can and are used for site-to-site hookups; see eg http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/security/security-howto/30353-how-to-set-up-a-site-to-site-vpn-with-openvpn and http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/115306.aspx .

Comment: you are right but in his case it is not possible. the question is about cisco asa (in my understanding).

Comment: I would agree the question's highly ambiguous, which is why I've asked the OP to clarify it.  When he does, I may ask you (trivially) edit your answer so i can remove the downvote (editing unlocks all locked-in votes).

Comment: edited my answer specific for cisco asa devices